# How can I retrieve a value in class inside a div tag using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am coding some VBA script that would get values of flights price from some website. But my code does not get the lowest price, it gets a random price...

I need retrieve some value in the code below.

I need retrieve the first **298** U$.
I've tried using

```
cia = doc.getElementsByClassName("currency ng-binding")(0).innerText
```

but it did not work.

My code:

```
<div class="box-filter cias" ng-init="opened = false">
                <h3>Cias. Aéreas</h3>
                <span>a partir de:</span>
                <div ng-class="(opened || hasFilter(AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies)) ? 'opened' : 'wrapper-cias'" id="wrapper-cia" class="opened">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="cias-aerea chkFilterAirCompany filterControl" value="All" ng-checked="!hasFilter(AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies)" ng-disabled="!hasFilter(AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies)" ng-click="SetFilter($event, 'all', 'Co');">
                        <strong class="label-option full">Todas as Companhias</strong>
                    </label>

                    <!-- ngRepeat: airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies --><label ng-repeat="airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies" ng-show="airCompany.MinPrice > 0 || airCompany.MinPoint > 0" class="ng-scope">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="cias-aerea chkFilterAirCompany filterControl ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" ng-model="airCompany.Checked" value="true" ng-click="SetFilter($event, airCompany.CiaCode, 'Co');">
                        <strong class="label-option ng-binding">Aeroméxico</strong>
                        <span class="price ng-binding" ng-show="!UsePoints"><span class="currency ng-binding">US$</span>**298**</span>
                        <!-- ngIf: UsePoints -->
                    </label><!-- end ngRepeat: airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies --><label ng-repeat="airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies" ng-show="airCompany.MinPrice > 0 || airCompany.MinPoint > 0" class="ng-scope">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="cias-aerea chkFilterAirCompany filterControl ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="airCompany.Checked" value="false" ng-click="SetFilter($event, airCompany.CiaCode, 'Co');">
                        <strong class="label-option ng-binding">Tam</strong>
                        <span class="price ng-binding" ng-show="!UsePoints"><span class="currency ng-binding">US$</span>549</span>
                        <!-- ngIf: UsePoints -->
                    </label><!-- end ngRepeat: airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies --><label ng-repeat="airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies" ng-show="airCompany.MinPrice > 0 || airCompany.MinPoint > 0" class="ng-scope">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="cias-aerea chkFilterAirCompany filterControl ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="airCompany.Checked" value="false" ng-click="SetFilter($event, airCompany.CiaCode, 'Co');">
                        <strong class="label-option ng-binding">Delta </strong>
                        <span class="price ng-binding" ng-show="!UsePoints"><span class="currency ng-binding">US$</span>907</span>
                        <!-- ngIf: UsePoints -->
                    </label><!-- end ngRepeat: airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies --><label ng-repeat="airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies" ng-show="airCompany.MinPrice > 0 || airCompany.MinPoint > 0" class="ng-scope">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="cias-aerea chkFilterAirCompany filterControl ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="airCompany.Checked" value="false" ng-click="SetFilter($event, airCompany.CiaCode, 'Co');">
                        <strong class="label-option ng-binding">Copa </strong>
                        <span class="price ng-binding" ng-show="!UsePoints"><span class="currency ng-binding">US$</span>1.028</span>
                        <!-- ngIf: UsePoints -->
                    </label><!-- end ngRepeat: airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies --><label ng-repeat="airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies" ng-show="airCompany.MinPrice > 0 || airCompany.MinPoint > 0" class="ng-scope">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="cias-aerea chkFilterAirCompany filterControl ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="airCompany.Checked" value="false" ng-click="SetFilter($event, airCompany.CiaCode, 'Co');">
                        <strong class="label-option ng-binding">American Airlines</strong>
                        <span class="price ng-binding" ng-show="!UsePoints"><span class="currency ng-binding">US$</span>1.180</span>
                        <!-- ngIf: UsePoints -->
                    </label><!-- end ngRepeat: airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies --><label ng-repeat="airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies" ng-show="airCompany.MinPrice > 0 || airCompany.MinPoint > 0" class="ng-scope">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="cias-aerea chkFilterAirCompany filterControl ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="airCompany.Checked" value="false" ng-click="SetFilter($event, airCompany.CiaCode, 'Co');">
                        <strong class="label-option ng-binding">Gol</strong>
                        <span class="price ng-binding" ng-show="!UsePoints"><span class="currency ng-binding">US$</span>1.278</span>
                        <!-- ngIf: UsePoints -->
                    </label><!-- end ngRepeat: airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies --><label ng-repeat="airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies" ng-show="airCompany.MinPrice > 0 || airCompany.MinPoint > 0" class="ng-scope">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="cias-aerea chkFilterAirCompany filterControl ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="airCompany.Checked" value="false" ng-click="SetFilter($event, airCompany.CiaCode, 'Co');">
                        <strong class="label-option ng-binding">LAN</strong>
                        <span class="price ng-binding" ng-show="!UsePoints"><span class="currency ng-binding">US$</span>1.985</span>
                        <!-- ngIf: UsePoints -->
                    </label><!-- end ngRepeat: airCompany in AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies -->

                </div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="opened = !opened" ng-hide="hasFilter(AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies) || AvailabilityResult.FilterOptions.AirCompanies.length <= 3" id="buttonViewAllCias" class="ver-todas ng-binding ng-hide">Ver todas as cias</a
            </div>
```

Comment: Not sure why the first one is not the lowest if they are always in sorted order.  You could also evaluate all 7 results and return the lowest (loop thru array, dictionary, etc...)

Comment: What if you use the class "price" instead of "currency ng-binding" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to go step by step to get what you need. The price you need is a `text-node` which is inside of a `price-span` which is inside of a `label` which is inside of a `wrapper-cia div`.

So first get the `div` then get second child of this `div` which is a`label`. Then get the `span` as third child of the `label` and finally get the `text-node` as second child of the `span`. HTH

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)
' Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim url As String

url = "file:///C:/Temp/ValueInsideDiv.html"
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate url

While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

Set doc = ie.document

Dim wrapperCia As MSHTML.HTMLDivElement
Set wrapperCia = doc.getElementById("wrapper-cia")

Dim ciaLabels As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection ' first has index 0, second 1 etc.
Set ciaLabels = wrapperCia.Children

Dim priceLabel As MSHTML.HTMLLabelElement
Set priceLabel = ciaLabels(1)

Dim priceLabelChildren As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Set priceLabelChildren = priceLabel.Children

Dim priceSpan As MSHTML.HTMLSpanElement
Set priceSpan = priceLabelChildren(2)

Dim priceNode As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMNode
Set priceNode = priceSpan.ChildNodes(1)

Dim price As String
price = priceNode.NodeValue

Debug.Print "Price = " & price

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
```

> Output

```
Price = **298**
```

Or if you want to do it a little bit more simpler (but more error prone) then just like this:

```
doc.getElementsByClassName("currency ng-binding")(0).NextSibling.NodeValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a well-formed HTML becomes a compliant valid XML, you could convert original document and then use an [XPath query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288913) which requires a slight cleanup of the HTML file to be well formed.

Specifically, removal of the accented `é` and replacing `>` and `<` with appropriate entities: `&gt;` and `&lt;` and properly closing the `<input>`nodes with `/>` will render a valid XML. Of course with larger html document more cleanup may be required but below uses posted content:

```
Sub ConvertAndParseWellFormedHTML()

    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim DataLine As String, htmlfile As String

    ' ADD VBA REFERENCE: MICROSOFT XML, v3.0 or v6.0 '
    Dim oXMLFile As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim ResultList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

    ' READ HTML FILE LINE BY LINE, CLEANING OUT PROBLEM XML VALUES '
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open "C:\Path\To\Locally\Saved.html" For Input As #FileNum

    htmlfile = ""
    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
        htmlfile = htmlfile + DataLine + vbNewLine

        htmlfile = Replace(Replace(Replace(htmlfile, " <=", "&lt;"), " > ", "&gt;"), ";"">", ";""/>")
        htmlfile = Replace(Replace(htmlfile, "é", "e"), "</a", "</a>")
    Wend

    ' LOAD XML CONTENT AS STRING ' 
    oXMLFile.LoadXML htmlfile

    ' EXTRACT NODES INTO LIST AND REWRITE NODES '
    ' (CHANGE NUMBER 1 FOR NODE POSITION TO GET OTHER PRICES) '
    Set ResultList = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/div/div/label[1]/span")

    Debug.Print ResultList(0).Text        

    Set ResultList = Nothing
    Set oXMLFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

```
US$**298**
```